# .htaccess configuration for https redirect and client routing

Tags: apache, vuejs2, vue-router

I have Apache 2.4.27 and two problems:

**1.** redirect http -> https

**2.** SPA (Vue2) client routing without #

Solution for **1**(it works):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Solution for **2**(Vue official recomendation):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

how to satisfy both conditions?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite\.domen [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

simple: solution1 + solution2 = it works